# Not able to fetch state defined using immutable fromJS in selector for my react-redux app

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, immutable.js, react-boilerplate

this is my selector file for `Login` component

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';
const authentication = () => (state) => state.get('login');
const getCurrentAuthData = () => createSelector(
  authentication,
  (loginState) => loginState.get('currentUser')
);
export {
  authentication,
  getCurrentAuthData,
};
```

and this is the reducer file which describes the state for `Login` component

```
import { fromJS } from 'immutable';
import { loginConstants } from './constant';

let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
const initialState = user ? fromJS({ loggedIn: true, user }) : fromJS({});

function loginReducer(state = initialState, action) {
   switch (action.type) {
   case loginConstants.LOGIN_REQUEST:
       return state
          .set('loggingIn', true)
          .set('user', action.true)
   case loginConstants.LOGIN_SUCCESS:
       return state
          .set('loggedIn', true)
          .set('user', action.true)
  case loginConstants.LOGIN_FAILURE:
       return fromJS({});
  case loginConstants.LOGOUT_REQUEST:
       return fromJS({});
  case loginConstants.LOGOUT_SUCCESS:
       return fromJS({});
  case loginConstants.LOGOUT_FAILURE:
       return fromJS({});
  default:
       return state
  } 
 }

 export default loginReducer;
```

**Now** the problem is it's giving error as loginState.get is not a function.

PS I am referencing the React-boilerplate [https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate] for code and basically copy-pasting code (learning phase).

Comment: I think you should look at this doc : https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/UsingImmutableJS.html

Comment: Already had looked into it but to no success. BUT the problem has been solved. What I did was change the statement
const authentication = () => (state) => state.get('login');
TO
const authentication = (state) => state.get('login');
[I had put an extra ()=>]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved, as expected there was in error in writing the statement.
I changed the statement from

```
const authentication = () => (state) => state.get('login');
//here it is returning a function to authentication
```

to

```
const authentication = (state) => state.get('login');
//here it is returning `state.get('login')` to authentication
```